# Select from two columns based on priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to combine two columns in SQL Server. However, I need to give one column priority.

```
Make    | Model      | Segment make | Segment model
--------+------------+--------------+--------------
Ferarri | California | Sport        | Null 
Ferarri | F40        | Sport        | Null 
Porsche | 911        | Sport        | Null 
Porsche | Cayenne    | Sport        | SUV
BMW     | M5         | Null         | Sport
```

I need a table with all the models and the segment of each car. All models have the segment in one of the two columns with segment. And, if there is a segment in both columns, would I like the segment for model to override the segment for the make, as in the example with the Porsche. This is the result I need:

```
Make    | Model      | Segment  
--------+------------+--------
Ferarri | California | Sport   
Ferarri | F40        | Sport     
Porsche | 911        | Sport    
Porsche | Cayenne    | SUV
BMW     | M5         | Sport
```

I have searched and found Rank(), but it does not seem to do what I want. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`. It returns it's first non-NULL parameter:

```
select, Make, Model, coalesce(Segmentmodel, Segmentmake) as segment
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce([Segment make], [Segment model]) as Segment
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment something like

```
select isnull(model,make) as segment
```

Because then you will always select the model, unless the model is empty. In that case it will select the make.

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

```
Select Make,Model,Coalesce([Segment model], [Segment make])  Segment From YourTable
```